# Is there any way we can transfer files from AWS Cloud to any local system?

Tags: file-transfer, aws-transfer-family

I have my files residing in AWS S3 bucket. I want to transfer them to a folder in an server. Can we use AWS Transfer family for this? In the documentation, it is mentioned that AWS transfer family can be used to transfer files  **to** **and** **from**  AWS storage services. But I couldn't find any use cases for transferring files **from**  AWS S3. And if they can be done, is there any way we can automate the file transfer. DO we need to use any other AWS service for that purpose?

Thanks in advance!

I haven't got much information from the internet about this.

Comment: Could you use [aws cli](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/)?

Comment: @SiKing Can you elaborate it please?

Comment: It's a command-line utility for copying files to / from an S3 bucket. As such you can call it from other scripts / processes.